# multiselect for a class that has 3 many-to-many relationship with 3 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 4 classes, 3 of them have many-to-many relationship with the main one Person. How can I create a multiselect dropdown for Person to select from the list of books, classes, and conferences? the person class has List of books, list of classes and list of conferences since a person can have more that one of each of these classes. The same thing goes for books, classes, and conferences. Each of these classes has a list of person since a book can have multiple writers, a class can have multiple instructors, and a conference can have multiple attendants. I'm not sure how to accomplish that and link the tables to each other. Any help will be much appreciated. I'm using entity framework code first.

Here's my classes:

```
public class Workshop
{
    public Workshop()
    {
        Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int WorkshopID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Session sessions { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public enum Session
{
    NewWorkshopPanels,
    Workshops,
    PanelSessions
}


  public class Paper
   {
       public Paper()
       {
        Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();            
    }


    [Key]
    public int PaperID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Short Title")]
    public string ShortTitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Paper Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Published Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]        
    public DateTime? PublishedDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Created")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]        
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Due Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]        
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Image Title")]
    public string imgTitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Image")]
    public string imgPath { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FileUsed> Files { get; set; }
}


public class Conference
    {
        public Conference()
        {
        Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ConferenceID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]        
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]       
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]        
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FileUsed> Files { get; set; }
}

 public class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
        paper = new HashSet<Paper>();
        workshop = new HashSet<Workshop>();
        conference = new HashSet<Conference>();
    }


    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Short Title")]
    public string ShortTitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Biography")]
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }

    public bool? IsHallFame { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Hall of Fame Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]        
    public DateTime? HallOfFameDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsInstructor { get; set; }
    public bool? IsTechnicalCommittee { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAuthor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstMidName+"  " +LastName; }
    }

    //public int? conferenceID { get; set; }
    //public int? PaperID { get; set; }
    //public int? WorkshopID { get; set; }

    public CustomerRole customerRole { get; set; }

    //public virtual Conference conference { get; set; }
    //public virtual Workshop workshop { get; set; }
    //public virtual Paper paper { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Conference> conference { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Workshop> workshop { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Paper> paper { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<FileUsed> Files { get; set; }


}

public enum CustomerRole
{
    Speaker = 1,
    Attendant = 2
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that one person can be a writer of a book as well as an instructor or an attendant of a conference.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempt in Modelling the DB structure. Use a tool like https://www.draw.io/

Comment: A multi-select dropdown will basically be the linking table which will have the Id of a class as a dropdown value, and the name of the class as display text.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually very helpful in creating the mutiselect. I ended up creating a class that acted as the middle between every two related classes and used it to create the multiselect dropdowns

Comment: YOU'RE welcome. Glad I could help